# Switch to another view when the button is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, button, view

I'm trying to have a button on my app take me to another view when it's pressed but for some reason t crashes all the time, i must be doing something crazy somehow. Here's what i have:
on the header:

```
@interface CCS : UIViewController {
UIButton * qsnBtn;}
```

`@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *qsnBtn;`

`-(IBAction)qsnBtnClicked:(id)sender;`

`@end`

on the .m file:

```
#import "CCS.h"
#import "QSN.h"

@implementation CCS
@synthesize qsnBtn;


//QSN Button
QSN *viewController;

-(IBAction)qsnBtnClicked:(id)sender {

    viewController = 
    [[QSN alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"QSN" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    //[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now i made all the connections on the .xib file but when on the CCS view which hold the button it doesn't take me to the QSN view. Someone please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of the QSN *viewController; line. And instead write something like `QSN *viewController = 
    [[QSN alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"QSN" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Tried getting rid of it and it's still not working.

Comment: Here's the error i have on the console [UIViewController qsnBtnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66490a0
2012-03-12 08:10:39.491 CCS[1108:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController qsnBtnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66490a0'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That

```
QSN *viewController;
```

Its not well placed there, you should do:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) QSN *viewController;
```

In the same place you have the other one

Comment: But what is going on? what is the crash?

Comment: well for one thing it's not taking me to the QSN view then it crashes and here's what i have on the console [UIViewController qsnBtnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66490a0
2012-03-12 08:10:39.491 CCS[1108:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController qsnBtnClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66490a0'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Ok so the problem is that your app cannot find qsnBtnClicked, are you sure you connections are made, and that method is declared in the , file?

Comment: yea when i go to the connection inspector i see that the button is connected to the file's owner and on the touch up inside

Comment: On my header file was i supposed to name the button qsnBtnclicked instead of qsnBtn?

Comment: No, the name is ok but you have to put: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *qsnBtn;

Comment: You wouldn't know a good tutorial on how to do this right would you?

Comment: Try with this one, it seems good: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/07/03/beignner-iphone-sdk-hello-world-tutorial-first-application/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Import your class(classname which you want to go while click on the button)

In my Case,

```
     #import"sample1.h"
```

Then allocate your class and add your class as a subview or navigate to that view

```
    sample1 *sam=[[sample1 alloc]init];

[self.view addSubview:sam.view];

     (or)

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sam animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the file's owner has been left as a UIViewController rather than a type CCS?

Comment: Open the view in Xcode. go to the identity inspector and check that the "Custom Class" for your view is set to CCS.